# windows authentication on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, authentication

I am trying to connect to a SQL server using Windows authentication. I am doing it through node js on Visual Studio.

The SQL server is on my machine itself.
It had worked fine for the connection string

```
var config = {
server: '10.2.9.208',                       
database: 'DFMProAnalyticsCopy',                            
user: 'sa',                                     
password: 'admin123#',
port: 1433                                      //default port number
};
```

But this was only for SQL authentication.

Now for Windows aunthentication, I have this connection string

```
var config = 
"Driver ={SQL Server};Server = 10.2.9.208;Database=DFMProAnalyticsCopy;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

This gives me error

```
Unknown driver SQL Server!
```

and this connection string

```
var config = 
"Server = 10.2.9.208;Database=DFMProAnalyticsCopy;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

gives error

```
Login failed for user ''
```

It is trying to attempt SQL authentication when I want Windows authentication. I have Mixed mode authentication ON.

I read at many places but am still unclear about it.

["Login failed for user ''" when trying to use Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659569/login-failed-for-user-when-trying-to-use-windows-authentication)

Please help me.

EDIT 1:

I cannot use the configuration string as in [SQL Server connection with jQuery and node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678380/sql-server-connection-with-jquery-and-node-js/37683068?noredirect=1#comment62869274_37683068) 
because mine is centralised and anyone could be using it, so I need to use Trusted_connection=true or Integrated security = SSPI. I dont have windows login credentials of people using the system.

Comment: So the first question is does your app pool worker service account have access to the SQL instance? Is it even a domain service account or still a local account?

Comment: Hi, I checked it. I have access to SQL instance & is a domain server account. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I had to provide an UID and password in the connection string, else it considered a null string for UID

```
var config = "Server={IPV4 of server};Database=dbname;Uid=domain\\username;Pwd=pwd";
```